# Why won't Ubuntu 13.04 load? (Only wallpaper)

Tags: 13.04

I just freshly installed 13.04 on an old HP 750n Pavillion desktop computer, connected to a Dell monitor. It has 512 MB RAM. When I login, it shows only the desktop and mouse, with no toolbar, icons, windows, etc. What could be causing this?

Thank you!
Ben

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen, except I couldn't even access the desktop at first.  If possible (CTRL+ALT+T I think) open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`.  After that, reboot and change the session to gnome fallback.  I do not have a fix for the problem, but try installing and using Cairo-desktop (my favorite) or gnome fallback until this bug is fixed.  Hope this helps!